# logical AND and OR in c

Tags: c

In a && b , this returns true if both a and b are equal to 1. If a=-1 and b=-1 then also the expression returns true.Similar is the case with a||b,where a=-1 and b=0,it returns true. Can anybody please explain the reason.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`a && b`  returns 1 when **both** `a` and `b` are **nonzero**, not just when they're equal to 1. Otherwise it returns 0.

`a || b` returns 1 when **at least one of** `a` or `b` is **nonzero**, not just when one of them is equal to 1. Otherwise it returns 0.

To give some examples:

```
   0 &&  0 -> 0
   1 &&  0 -> 0
   1 &&  1 -> 1
   2 &&  1 -> 1
  -1 && -1 -> 1
-100 &&  0 -> 0

   0 ||  0 -> 0
   1 ||  0 -> 1
   0 ||  1 -> 1
  -1 ||  0 -> 1
-100 || 20 -> 1
```

Comment: Thanks nightcracker ,I really had a very big misconception :)

Comment: @sourabh912: if my answer solved your problem you can mark it as the answer by clicking the green tickbox to the left of my question.

Comment: I may be wrong, but doesn't "when either a or b are nonzero" mean "one and only one of them is nonzero"? If you write "when at least one of a and b is nonzero", the difficulty of the precise meaning of "either" is circumvented.

Comment: @DanielFischer: changed wording.

Answer (score 10):

*C11 (n1570) §6.5.13 al 3 p 99* say :

> The && operator shall yield 1 if both of its operands compare unequal to 0; otherwise, it
>   yields 0.

-1 is a nonzero value, so `-1 && -1` is `1`.

Answer (score 2):

On the [MSDN page for &&](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z68fx2f1%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

> The logical-AND operator produces the value 1 if both operands have nonzero values.

Clearly both operands are -1 in your example so they will produce 1.

On the same page, listed for `||`

> If either operand has a nonzero value, the result is 1.

In your case one operand is -1, therefore the result is 1

Comment: __Please__ don't refer to MSDN.

Comment: @nightcracker what SHOULD I refer to? Every reference is ultimately a derrivitave of the spec. Why shouldnt't I chose MSDN over any other reference?

Comment: Because this behaviour is __specified__ (not implementation-dependant) by the C specification, and MSVC has no choice on implementing this. Refer to the C99 or C11 spec instead.

Comment: @nightcracker: Since they have to be the same, what difference does it make?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: because this question is tagged `c`, not `msvc`.

Comment: @nightcracker: Right, but they have to be the same, so what difference does it make?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: even though they __have to be__ the same, Microsoft has the annoying tendency with things to not do it (though probably not for the `&&` operator). This goes for more compiler vendors, though. By following the __official__ standard you have the __guarantee__ it works, and if it doesn't you can complain at your compiler vendor.

Comment: @nightcracker I don't know this article is entitled "C Logical Operators" indicating its a reference to the language, not some wonky internal thingy.

Comment: @nightcracker: I guess this is some kind of religious issue for you or something. The citation is to a reference from a reliable source that precisely explains the OP's issue. Yes, there might be other cases where that source has incorrect or inapplicable information, but this is not one of those cases. The MSDN page, in this case, has precisely the same information, just phrased slightly more clearly.

Answer (score 1):

AND returns 1 if both operands have non-zero values. 
OR returns 1 if either operand has a non-zero value.

Answer (score 1):

and operator i.e (&&) will proceed only if both the conditions are true , wheree as in the case of or operator i.e(||) will proceed if atleast one of he two condition is true..

Answer (score 0):

Logical operators return either 0 or 1.
The && operator returns 1 if both its operands are not 0.Else,it return 0.
statements like if(x),while(x) etc.. get executed if its argument is not 0.For all other +ve and -ve arguments it get executed.